# Linux anacron redo an interrupted job?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a daily backup script that's run by anacron. Suppose that anacron starts the script, but I turn off the computer while the script is running. Is there functionality/a way that anacron can detect that a script failed to complete and run the script again the next time that the computer is turned on?

Answer (score 1):

You could write the backup script to leave a log file, then write a second cron that runs every hour or so and check the time stamp, if it's more than say 28 hours, run your backup.

Comment: Sounds like a nasty workaround, but indeed I don't think `anacron` can do it. That said, as `anacron` also won't start the job if the computer was simply not running at the scheduled time, it might be easier to make the backup script itself determine when the last backup completed successfully and start a new backup if 24 hour passed. And then run that script using `cron` every hour or even more often. (So, not use `anacron` at all.)

Comment: Yeap. Or define a logical window of when backup are allowed, and have cron check periodically in that window if a backup and run, and if not for 24, start it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, anacron detects that:

anacron will only update the time stamp in
`/var/spool/anacron/<job name>`
when a job finished. `job name` refers to the 3rd entry of a job in `/etc/anacrontab`.

Thus when a job such as a monthly backup is started by anacron, and while it runs the computer is shut down, the time stamp in the file above is not updated. So when anacron starts next time, for instance a day later, it will start the monthly backup then (and not a month later).